# Blog only showing one post why even though all are published,

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Why is my WordPress blog.php only showing one blog entry while I have two entries in the blog at present?  I have verified that both are published.  And I do have my reading setup to my blog page.  Any ideas?.

http://kvalixhu.digitalthinkersni.co.uk/blog/

```
<?php /* Template Name: BlogPosts */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="contentWrap" class="group">

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        <div id="article">
        <?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page=5'.'&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>


            <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p> Posted By <?php the_author(); ?></p>

                <div id="entryItem">
                <?php the_content(); ?>

                </div><!--entryItem-->      

        </div><!--article-->
<?php endwhile; ?>

    </div><!--contentWrap-->

</div><!--mainWrapper-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Isn't `$wp_query = null;` within the `while` resetting the object you are trying to loop through, resulting in no other items to loop through and therefore only the first one is displayed

Comment: @Tristan what should i change to fix it  Tristan

Comment: What is the rationale for `<?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>`? It seems like it is the cause of your problem and should be removed.

Comment: @Tristan even if i remove the line complety it still has same effect even though reading settings is set to that page template and set to show 10 posts ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Put article opening tag inside the loop

I assume, that you want to wrap each posts with a `article` div. Since more than one container with the same is not allow, you should change this to a `class`.

### Remove `$temp`

Why are you using `$temp`? Just remove this, and don't set `$wp_query` to `null`.

```
<?php /* Template Name: BlogPosts */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="contentWrap" class="group">

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        <?php
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page=5'.'&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>

        <div class="article">

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p> Posted By <?php the_author(); ?></p>

                <div id="entryItem">
                <?php the_content(); ?>

                </div><!--entryItem-->      

        </div><!--article-->
<?php endwhile; ?>

    </div><!--contentWrap-->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: worked like a charm removed my reading settings and used your code question how would one get pagination to show ?

Comment: Great! [This page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination) on the WordPress Codex should help you out. There lots of [examples](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Example_Loop_with_Pagination).

Comment: I am trying to create this layout where the image is on the left and text flowing properly on right any ideas budy . http://pasteboard.co/NdWVjh5.jpg

Comment: i dont want to add another frame work could i not do it with css at the way it is

Comment: could you do a demostration at all in the answer ?.

Comment: This isn't related to the question and doesn't make sense on SO.